# Focus Collection view item

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to focus a collection view's particular item, So I am using  the delegate method but its not being called

```
func indexPathForPreferredFocusedView(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> IndexPath? {

    let indexpath = IndexPath.init(row: 7 , section: 0)
    return indexpath
}
```

Comment: Did you set the delegate of collectionView?

Comment: yes it set the ui collectionview delegate but still. its not getting called

Comment: Can you please add more code explaining the issue?